# C++ templated class with different behaviour depending on type

Tags: c++, templates

say you have a class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

And within a method, is there any way to have different behaviour depending on the type like that:

```
template <typename T> MyClass::doSomething() {
    //this is what I want:
    std::string value = "17";
    if(T == int) {
         int myInt = atoi(value.c_str());
    } else if(T == std::string) {
         std::string myString = value;
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?
I know I could write a wrapper class that provides a constructor that takes a `std::string`, so I could use something like:

`T myVar(value);`

But that would be more resource wasting if using simple type like an `int`, also I would like to realize that if-else-statement to be able to perform different actions.

I would be thankful for an answer.
regards,

tagelicht

Comment: Couldn't you use template specialization?

Comment: i didnt think of that but Im worried that using template specification might make the class usable only for certain types? I want to stay as flexible as possible with this

Comment: @tagelicht, specialization is more flexible than any kind of `if`, because you can add specializations as needed and you can add partial specializations to cover more complicated sets of types which you can't do with the static ifs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++17, you can achieve exactly what you want with `if constexpr(...)`:

```
template <typename T> MyClass::doSomething() {
    //this is what I want:
    std::string value = "17";
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
         int myInt = atoi(value.c_str());
    } else constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
         std::string myString = value;
    }
}
```

---

In C++14, you can implement your own `static_if` quite easily. I gave [a tutorial talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k) about this at CppCon 2016 and Meeting C++ 2016.

```
template <typename T> MyClass::doSomething() {
    //this is what I want:
    std::string value = "17";
    static_if(std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        .then([&](auto) {
             int myInt = atoi(value.c_str());
        })
        .else_if(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) 
        .then([&](auto) {
             std::string myString = value;
        })();
}
```

---

In C++11, you probably want to use *function overloading* or *template specialization*. Example with the former *(updated with suggestions from [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) in the comments)*:

```
template <typename> struct tag { };

void call_dispatch(...) { } // lowest priority

void call_dispatch(tag<std::string>) 
{ 
    std::string myString = value; 
}

void call_dispatch(tag<int>) 
{ 
    int myInt = atoi(value.c_str()); 
}
```

Usage:

```
template <typename T> MyClass::doSomething() {
    //this is what I want:
    std::string value = "17";
    call_dispatch(tag<T>{});
}
```

Comment: tag dispatching (`call(tag<T>{});`) seems better than `call_if_int(..); call_if_string(..)`

Comment: All these approaches are very bad code-smell. Yes, the questions asks for exactly this, but a trait type would be a better approach in vast majority of cases. That is static analog of visitor pattern v.s. if-chain for dynamically polymorphic objects.

Comment: @JanHudec: I disagree - it depends on the scope and reusability of the compile-time branch. If it's a small and reasonably local branch, a trait is overkill compared to `if constexpr`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, it it's small, then yes, but the OP comments “I want to stay as flexible as possible with this” and if constexpr is definitely *not* that.

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches not yet exemplified are 1) *tag dispatch* and 2) *template specialization*

#### Tag dispatch:

- Call a helper function that uses overloading

The way we do this is to define some empty templated struct as a lightweight "tag" type:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    public:
    void doSomething();
    private:
    // tag for dispatch
    template<class U>
    struct doSomethingTag{};
```

... and then define helper functions that take specializations of that tag:

```
    void doSomethingHelper(doSomethingTag<std::string>, std::string value);
    void doSomethingHelper(doSomethingTag<int>, std::string value);
};
```

Then we can use the primary entry point (`doSomething`) as a way to call the specialized helper function:

```
template <typename T> 
void MyClass<T>::doSomething() {

    //dispatch to helper function
    doSomethingHelper(doSomethingTag<T>{}, "17");
}
```

### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89b6d1e490edefcd)

The helper functions look like this:

```
template <typename T> 
void MyClass<T>::doSomethingHelper(doSomethingTag<std::string>, std::string value)
{
    int myInt = atoi(value.c_str());
}

template <typename T> 
void MyClass<T>::doSomethingHelper(doSomethingTag<int>, std::string value)
{
    std::string myString = value;
}
```

This should incur **no overhead** for the tag structures because the helper functions don't actually use the tag parameter, so it'll be optimized away. If it's not, it is a 1-byte overhead to construct the struct. (Note: Vittorio Romeo [hinted at this in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43045577/27678), but he called it "function overloading")

---

#### Template specialization

You can "specialize" the template for your function so long as you are fully specializing it (specify the type for the class!):

The syntax for specialization looks a little strange because we keep the angle-brackets empty: `<>`:

```
template<> 
void MyClass<int>::doSomething() {

    //dispatch to helper function
    std::string value = "17";
    int myInt = atoi(value.c_str());
}

template <>
void MyClass<std::string>::doSomething()
{
    std::string value = "17";
    std::string myString = value;
}
```

This enables you to keep a smaller class:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

### [Demo 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2001d973568a6458)

---

#### Conclusion:

In the specific example you've given, I'd prefer template specialization. However, oftentimes you want to do some kind of partial specialization, and this gets very very strange with member functions, so tag dispatch is often preferred.

With C++17, using [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) definitely makes life easier.

Comment: @tagelicht: You are welcome. Hopefully one day the C++ community here will be considered less [angry](https://hackernoon.com/which-programming-languages-have-the-happiest-and-angriest-commenters-ebe91b3852ed) than they have in the past

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> MyClass::doSomething() {
    //this is what I want:
    std::string value = "17";
    if(std::is_same<T,int>::value) {
         int myInt = atoi(value.c_str());
    } else if(std::is_same<T,std::string>::value) {
         std::string myString = value;
    }
}
```

This is C++11. You can make it even nicer with C++17 with `constexpr if`. Here there's the problem that you have to cast the values that are not implicitly castable. For example, return of `std::string` has to be cast to int for this to compile.

Comment: This approach requires both branches to be valid even if the condition is not met - you should mention that when comparing it to `if constexpr`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I did.

Comment: thhanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach primarily because the blocks within all branches must compile for every type.

Comment: @AndyG It doesn't affect performance at all, though. If you want to use templates, there's no way around it in C++11.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: I didn't say anything about performance. If you're lucky enough for it to compile, great. But the pattern is brittle. There are many other alternative approaches to what OP wants. We are not constrained to keep the `if...else` branch-like syntax.